# Not Authenticated Error in Django using Stripe

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am creating for the very first time a payment for an e-commerce website using stripe, I am following a guide and have reviewed every step carefully but always getting Not Authenticated Error and I'm unclear what is going wrong.

I am new to Django so I'm trying to learn as much as possible from my errors.

Here is my views.py

```
class PaymentView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # order
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        context = {
            'order': order
        }
        return render(self.request, "payment.html", context)

# `source` is obtained with Stripe.js; see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges#web-create-token
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
        token = self.request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        amount = int(order.get_total() * 100)

        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=amount,  # cents
                currency="usd",
                source=token,
            )
            # create payment
            payment = Payment()
            payment.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            payment.user = self.request.user
            payment.amount = order.get_total()
            payment.save()

            # assign the payment to the order
            order.ordered = True
            order.payment = payment
            order.save()

            messages.success(self.request, "Your Order was Successful ! ")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            body = e.json_body
            err = body.get('error', {})
            messages.error(self.request, f"{err.get('message')}")
            # Since it's a decline, stripe.error.CardError will be caught
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.RateLimitError as e:
            # Too many requests made to the API too quickly
            messages.error(self.request, "Rate Limit Error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.InvalidRequestError as e:
            # Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
            messages.error(self.request, "Invalid Parameters")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.AuthenticationError as e:
            # Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            # (maybe you changed API keys recently)
            messages.error(self.request, "Not Authenticated")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.APIConnectionError as e:
            # Network communication with Stripe failed
            messages.error(self.request, "Network Error")
            return redirect("/")

        except stripe.error.StripeError as e:
            # Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            # yourself an email
            messages.error(
                self.request, "Something went wrong. You were not charged. Please Try Again.")
            return redirect("/")

        except Exception as e:
            # Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
            # send an email to ourselves
            messages.error(
                self.request, "A serious Error Occured. We have been notified.")
            return redirect("/")
```

here is my model.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

and here is the forms.py

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    street_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': '1234 Main St',
        'class': 'form-control'
    }))
    apartment_address = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Apartment or suite',
        'class': 'form-control'
    }))
    province = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control'
    }))
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)').formfield(
        widget=CountrySelectWidget(attrs={
            'class': 'custom-select d-block w-100'
        }))
    postal_code = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control'
    }))
    same_shipping_address = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    save_info = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    payment_option = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES)
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi Ahmed, where are you importing and initializing stripe-python? You should have a line somewhere where you: `import stripe` followed by `stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xyz"` Usually when you see the type of error you're seeing it's either that you forgot to add api key or you've added the wrong one.

Comment: i have already views ```stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY``` so I should add in the settings the ```stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xyz"```

Comment: thank you so much it worked

Comment: That's great! Glad I could help :)

Comment: @ttmarek post it to accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am following a guide and have reviewed every step carefully but
>   always getting Not Authenticated Error and I'm unclear what is going
>   wrong.

When you see this type of error from Stripe it usually means that you haven't provided a secret key, or have provided a mal-formed string as a secret key (it should be of the form `sk_test_xyz` (for test mode) or `sk_live_xyz` (for live mode).

I would double-check that you have a line where you `import stripe` followed by another line setting the API key as follows:

```
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xyz"
```